# Overriding default activation workflow

Tags: workflow, replication, aem

My project is currently running a CQ 5.4 implementation. We have a requirement that asks us to modify the existing page replication process (initiated via "Activate Page" in the sidekick or through the websites console). I have two questions:

Is it possible to inspect and modify the code attached to the activation process?
Is it possible to override the default activation process with custom code? If so, how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to inspect the workflow at /libs/foundation/workflows.    Override by copying it to /apps